# Comparison of strings not working in an if else statement

Tags: javascript

Please look at the code below:

```
function chooseVehicle(option1, option2) {
 if(option1 > option2){
   return option1 + " is clearly the better choice."
 }else if(option1 < option2){
   return option2 + " is clearly the better choice."
 }
}

console.log(chooseVehicle('Bugatti Veyron', 'Ford Pinto'))
```

Because of the letter  "B" is before the letter "F" i wanted the output to be for example:

```
  console.log(chooseVehicle('Bugatti Veyron', 'Ford Pinto'))

  "Bugatti Veyron is clearly the better choice."
```

Instead the output was:

```
  "Ford Pinto is clearly the better choice."
```

I would appreciate it if someone would help me on this problem in javascript.

Comment: `B` is earlier in alphabet so it's less than `F`. Change `>` to `<`

Comment: you are not understanding that ">" means "lower" alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

you can't compare alphabetical order using assignment operators in javascript.
instead, use `localeCompare()`

```js
function chooseVehicle(option1, option2) {
 if(option1.localeCompare(option2)){
   return option1 + " is clearly the better choice."
 }else if(option2.localeCompare(option1)){
   return option2 + " is clearly the better choice."
 }
}

console.log(chooseVehicle('Bugatti Veyron', 'Ford Pinto'));
```

or use `.toLowerCase()` first before comparing.